# Retirar mensagens do validate() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom pessoal, estou fazendo um formulário e estou usando o firebase para armazenar o banco, porém o firebase não aceita corretamente a função "submit" dos formulários, estão estou usando o validate() do jquery, só que ficam motrando mensagens como no exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria de saber como retirar essas mensagens e contar o tanto de inputs que não estão corretos. Verifiquei esse site https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ , porém não consegui.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método `resetForm()`

```
 var validator = $("#myform").validate(
       ...
       ...
    );

    $(".cancel").click(function() {
        validator.resetForm();
    });
```

Fonte: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html